# API renren.com with nodejs

Tags: node.js, request, social-networking, express

i need to call `like.getCount` from the [renren.com API](http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/API)
i can't understand chinese and with google translator i can't fully understand how to make the call i have already this code in nodejs but it doesn't work:

```
var postdata='[{"v":"1.0","call_id":"1333106764755", "urls":urltest}]' ;
var finalurl = 'http://api.renren.com/restserver.do';
request({  url: finalurl ,  headers: default_headers,  method: 'POST',  body: postdata},
function(error, response, body) {

    var result= JSON.parse(body);

    console.log(result);
});
```

Someone can help me pls?

I have this code:

```
var postdata='[{"v":"1.0","call_id":"1333106764755","method":"like.getCount", "urls":'+urltest+'}]' ;
var finalurl = 'http://api.renren.com/restserver.do';
var default_headers = { 'Content-type': 'application/json' };

request({  url: finalurl ,  headers: default_headers,  method: 'POST',  body: postdata},
function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

i always get `error_code=101` , `error_msg=???api_key??????????`, is there an easy way to call this ren api? like in Facebook or twitter maybe using a nodejs module or something?

Comment: Please indicate what's specifically going wrong, rather than just "doesn't work".

Comment: did you check this http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/API_Invocation ?

Comment: Also, you don't seem to have the required parameters as described here: http://wiki.dev.renren.com/wiki/Like.getCount (api_key, method, sig are noted as required)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **api_key** also in the request, you can **signup** for a developer account here http://app.renren.com/developers and can create an app where you will get the api_key.